# Issue with Netbeans on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, netbeans, java

I just installed Netbeans using the script on Oracle's website and I'm having some trouble getting it to work.  After opening Netbeans I went to open up a simple .java file just to test it out and got this error:

"The JDK is missing and is required to run some Neatbeans modules.  Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation or see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for more information."

I have OpenJDK, and I'm not sure what's meant by using the --jdkhome command line option.  I also visited the wiki and it's about doing a full installation of JDK, which I don't think I should need to do.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you used this file (netbeans-8.1-linux.sh) to install netbeans ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's **better to use Oracle Java JDK rather than Open JDK** if you want to use Netbeans for java development

> You can use this [link](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1372) to set Oracle Java JDK in Linux Mint
>
> So, it's better to follow theses instructions (JDK install) prior to Netbeans install and all things will go well.

```
Steps:

1-Remove OpenJDK installation
  sudo apt-get update && apt-get remove openjdk*

2- Download Oracle JDK you want to install (for example JDK 8)
   Download the *.tar.gz one.
   example for current version: jdk-8u65-linux-x64.tar.gz

3- Extract the file and create a folder where to move it
   tar -zxvf jdk-8u65-linux-x64.tar.gz
   sudo mkdir -p /opt/java
   sudo mv jdk1.8.0_65 /opt/java

4- Make JDK system default
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java"  
        "/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java" 1

   sudo update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java
```

> At this stage, you can start the installation of Netbeans IDE and **it will automatically detect your Oracle JDK setting**

I tested a short HelloWorld Java example, and I don't have any issue.

[image]

Here is the setting JDK view in Netbeans:

[image]

If you want to add the JAVA Home dir to your system

Proceed like this

You have to be in root mode and then edit this file: **/etc/bash.bashrc**
and add:

```
#JAVA HOME 
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_65 
export JAVA_HOME 
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin 
export PATH
```

Reboot your Mint system

Now you'll have **javac** working in command line...

Comment: In your opinion can this still be expected to work after the Netbeans install?  Also, is there any clean way to remove Netbeans after using Oracle's installation script?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by expected to work? The Netbeans Ide recognize the JDK so you will use the full potential of your NetBeans for Java development. Is this what you want?

Comment: There is a file named **uninstall.sh** in the NetBeans install dir (/usr/local/netbeans-8.1 in this case) witch you can run to cleanly uninstall NetBeans. [How to uninstall NetBeans?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76908/how-to-uninstall-netbeans)

Comment: I meant installing Oracle JDK after installing Netbeans, so maybe Netbeans will still be using OpenJDK.  I did the uninstall and will try a complete reinstall using these steps soon.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to install JDK after NetBeans install try to go to the **menu tools** and then to **Java platform Manager** to manage the location directory of the JDK. You can then try to remove the open JDK from there. I cannot test that because I already removed the open JDK from my Mint system.

Comment: Thanks again.  After doing this however 'javac' no longer works from the command line.  I could do something like alias it to the javac in the Oracle directory, but is there another way of doing this?  The 'sudo update-alternatives --set' didn't seem to work with javac.

Comment: I've added the solution for **javac** to the answer.